# I have two arrays.I want to check which is the common element in php

Tags: php

Imgagining i have two array

```
arr[]={"red","blue","green"}
arr2[]={"red","violet","black"}
```

How will i compare the two array to get the result that i common to both of the arrays..

For this the result is red...

How wil i do this in php(simple means)...Can anyone suggest???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it quick:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

The function takes multiple array and returns an array with ONLY elements that are in every single array.

### Multidimensional

This snippet takes all the multidimensional arrays and UNIONS the array together before INTERSECTING the results:
`($multi1[0] U $multi1[1] U ... U $multi1[n]) INTERSECT ($multi2[0] U $multi2[1] U ... U $multi2[m])`:

```
$result = null;
foreach(array($multi1, $multi2, $multi3) as $multi) {
    $merge = array();
    foreach($multi as $array) {
      $merge = array_merge($merge, $array);
    }
    if($result == null) {
      $result = $merge;
    } else {
      $result = array_intersect($merge, $result);
    }
}
```

This snippet takes all the multidimensional arrays and UNIONS the array together before INTERSECTING the results:
`($multi1[0] INTERSECT  $multi1[1] INTERSECT ... INTERSECT $multi1[n]) INTERSECT ($multi2[0] INTERSECT $multi2[1] INTERSECT ... INTERSECT $multi2[m])`:

```
$result_all = null;
foreach(array($multi1, $multi2, $multi3) as $multi) {
    $result = null;
    foreach($multi as $array) {
      if($result == null) {
        $result = $array;
      } else {
        $result = array_intersect($array, $result);
      }
    }
    if($result_all == null) {
      $result_all = $result;
    } else {
      $result_all = array_intersect($result, $result_all);
    }
}
```

### EDIT - Recursion

To make it simpler to read i made it recursive for the INTERSECT all case:

```
function array_intersect_multi($arrays, $dim = 1) {
    $result = null;
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
      $tmp = $dim > 1 ? array_intersect_multi($array, $dim - 1) : $array;
      if($result == null) {
        $result = $tmp;
      } else {
        $result = array_intersect($tmp, $result);
      }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

used like this:

```
$array1 = array(array('1', '2', '3'), array('3', '5', '0'));
$array2 = array(array('5', '3', '7'), array('3', '7', '8'));
$result = array_intersect_multi(array($array1, $array2), 3);
```

notice the dimension 3 since the array we are passing in is:

```
array(
  array(
    array('1', '2', '3'),
    array('3', '5', '0')
  ),
  array(
    array('5', '3', '7'),
    array('3', '7', '8')
  )
)
```

The result should be:

`array('3')`

Comment: IF i have a multidimensional array will i be able to implement this(like for example a two dimenstion array)..Can you give me an example on how it works for two dimensional array if possibe;

Comment: Don't forget you can use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) for your first snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "violet", "black", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
)
```